# Yii can't open PHP file from browser

Tags: php, yii, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have installed module "YCM" to my Yii project. With him are expanding CKEditor + CKFinder. I'm trying to upload an image from CKFinder, got an error:

> > Unable to process request "assets/c3da22c3/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php"

This file exists, but Yii for some reason does not want to open it.

Comment: Does the file have the right rights?

Comment: 1 hint: the url of the connector.php is relative so if you have enable urlRewrite this could be the problem.